# Good way to state, in english, the negation of "$f$ equals zero almost everywhere".

Tags: measure-theory, logic, proof-writing, article-writing

Let $X = (X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$. Consider the statement:

> $f$ equals zero almost everywhere

Is there an concise, unambiguous way of stating the negation of this statement? One shouldn't really just say something like

> $f$ does not equal zero almost everywhere

because this could be interpreted as meaning that the complement of the set $\{x : f(x) \neq 0\}$ has measure zero. The best I've been able to come up with are variations on

> It is *not* the case that $f$ equals zero almost everywhere

but this seems a bit clunky to me. Any advice?

Comment: What about $f$ equals zero not almost everywhere?

Comment: @quid: That's a decent suggestion, +1.

Comment: Is the statement a hypothesis or the conclusion? If it's a hypothesis, you can write "... unless $f$ equals zero a.e."

Comment: I'm not sure it is any less clunky, but my first thoughts go to: there exists a set $E$ of positive measure such that $f(x)\neq0$ for a.e. $x\in E$.

Answer (score 2):

One concise way of expressing this is to say

> $f$ is nonzero on a set of positive measure

Alternatively, you could try

> The zeros of $f$ do not have full measure

though I prefer the first.

Answer (score 1):

Some people like to talk about a function's "support". In these terms the property you state can be concisely stated as

> $f$ has support of positive measure

or maybe

> $f$ has nontrivial support

You could also just interchange the words a bit to get

> $f$ is not almost-everywhere zero

which is unambiguous (but does sound a little funny).

Comment: It's barely a problem, but some people like to close the support when there is a topology lying around. So, depending on how "to the letter" an author wants to be, you could argue that, say, the characteristic function of the rational numbers is the whole real line.

Comment: I like your last suggestion. It sounds just a tiny bit funny, but not too bad. I think I will adopt it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My vote is

> $f$ does not vanish almost everywhere.

I suppose that *could* be misinterpreted in the same way as "$f$ is not zero almost everywhere" but somehow that seems much less likely with this version; I can't define precisely why.